# MacOS: NSPredicate find where "one to one" relationship is not nil

Tags: macos, core-data, nspredicate

I am trying to use `NSPredicate` to filter a Core Data fetch request. The predicate string looks like this:

```
"stringProperty = %@ && dateProperty > %@ && oneToOneRelationship != nil"
```

This is isn't returning any objects. However, if I omit the last clause it does. If I change the last clause to be `"oneToOneRelationship = nil"` then it does. Of course, these last two cases don't return the data I really want. :)

Is there a proper way to search for one-to-one relationships where the relationship exists and isn't nil? It seems like that predicate should be working but it isn't. This is on the current Yosemite beta using Xcode 6.1 beta.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the "!= nil" test is working just fine. It turns out that although I thought the one-to-one relationship was being set, in fact, it wasn't. So, the predicate was working properly. It was, of course, my code that was in error.

Answer (score 4):

Use `oneToOneRelationship.@count != 0`. The following code should work:

*Swift:*

```swift
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "stringProperty == %@ && dateProperty > %@ && oneToOneRelationship.@count != 0", argumentArray:[stringProperty, dateProperty])
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
```

*Objective-C:*

```c
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"stringProperty == %@ && dateProperty > %@ && oneToOneRelationship.@count != 0", stringProperty, dateProperty];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: Oddly enough (well, oddly to me), that worked! I wouldn't have expected @count to work for a one-to-one relationship. Curiously though testing for "@count != 0" worked though testing for "@count = 1" didn't. Gotta love the vagaries of NSPredicate...

Comment: Actually, the @count isn't working for one-to-one relationships. The original != nil test is working. It turns out the relationship wasn't getting set so, of course, it wasn't being found by the fetch request.